# Elastic Search Returning the Same Scroll ID

Tags: elasticsearch, infinite-scroll, elasticsearch-dsl

Elastic Search returning the same **scroll Id** for each request but data state vary. Its working fine for pagination.

But I need to maintain the **scroll Id** in my **stack**, so I can scroll up/down for all documents a/c to pagination, 10 documents at a time. I need to avoid/reduce/optimize browser memory to contain only 10 documents as per requirement instead all documents.

**e.g**

1st request give me 10(1-10) documents with **scroll ID** scroll_id_1. I push this into my stack.

2nd request give me next 10(11-20) documents with recent **scroll ID** i.e scroll_id_1 gives me new **scroll ID** again scroll_id_1. I push this into my stack.

Now if I want to **scroll up** to see the previous 10(1-10) documents has **scroll ID** scroll_id_1 give me new next 10(21-30) documents. Here is the problem is there any way to tackle this ? Generating custom **scroll id** so i can easily scroll up/down a/c to my requirements.

I read this on Official Documentation of Elastic Search seems not possible.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First off, the Scroll API should not be used for real-time pagination, it's only meant for batch pagination.

Second, the Scroll API is only meant as a forward only pagination, there's no support for forward/backward pagination.

You should investigate the [`search_after` pagination](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) instead which is more lightweight and allows back and forth pagination... It also allows you to preserve the index state using a [point in time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after)

Also if you're not scrolling further than the first 10000 documents, [`from`/`size` pagination](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#paginate-search-results) is all you need

Answer (score 0):

You may use pageIndex and pageSize. And use a loop for `from` parameter.

You can get first 10 documnets with `"from": 0,"size": 10` and for next 10 document use `"from": 11,"size": 10`

```
{ "from": 0,   
  "size": 10,    
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "FIELD": {
              "value": "VALUE"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```